# How to fix : module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I am trying to monitor my neural network by using `keras.callbacks`, but I get this error.

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'
```

Code for reference:

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your TF version is 2.5 use

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
```

Or you can downgrade your TF version to 2.1.

```
pip install tensorflow==2.1.0
```